# How to inspect a module

Tags: ruby

How can I find out the constructs (methods, constants, etc.) defined in a module?

Let's say there's `require 'observer'`, and I would like to see all that are defined within 'observer'. How can I?

Comment: `puts` or `inspect` won't show, unfortunately.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You `require` files, not modules. If you want to see the contents of a file, you can simply open and print it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use pry, simply do `ls ModuleName`

`ls` shows all the available methods and instance variables of a certain module or class or instance. More about pry: http://pryrepl.org/

Or you can do

`ModuleName.instance_methods` to get instance_methods

`ModuleName.instance_variables` to get instance_variables

As another answer state, it's almost impossible (still doable in a brittle way) to get a full picture of what you require by just an arbitrary `require`

imo, this kind of implementation itself is brittle and prone to error, unless its your own module and you have full control of the API. But still not a good idea.

Comment: What's the module name for an arbitrary `require`?

Comment: I guess you can assume the module follows ruby convention and its name to be `Observer`. But it's not for certain.

Comment: When you assume things like that, you're basically hoping that the module doesn't define anything else, plus that everything is loaded up front, that nothing is deferred or lazy-evaluated. Most gems, especially older ones, are full of surprises.

Comment: You're right. Hoping to get a full picture of a module or what the file includes by the arbitrary `require` is a brittle implementation anyway imo.

Comment: You're not wrong in that these methods tell you what's happened, but they can't predict the future, nor what other things that dependency introduced.

Comment: I would say avoid this implementation at all cost. This is relying on others to follow your assumption. Wrong assumption at the first place. And a gem without well implemented API is likely a bad gem. so its a bad implementation using a bad gem... oops

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't, not with absolute certainty.

Long answer: This a product of how Ruby is a very dynamic language at its core and imposes almost no constraints on what a `require` statement might do. Any number of modules and classes can be created by a library, and there's no requirement for these to be grouped together neatly.

Even if you go through the trouble of taking a snapshot of all defined classes and methods before you require it, and then another one after to find out what's been added there's no assurance you've captured them all. Some classes might be loaded or defined well after the `require` statement is finished.

The best way to find out is to read through the source. There you'll see all the different modules and classes that *could* be defined even if they're not triggered by your code.

Reflection tools like `methods` help to a degree, but it's also highly misleading. Methods can be defined at a later point in time, you may need to exercise the code more thoroughly for them to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute `Observer` methods from outside the module you wish to examine. Here is an example of what you might do.

```
module Observer
  def self.show_all(mod)
    puts "owner of methods = #{mod.methods(false)}"
    puts "owner of instance methods = #{mod.instance_methods(false)}"
    puts "instance variables = #{mod.instance_variables}"
    puts "ancestors = #{mod.ancestors}"
    puts "included modules = #{mod.included_modules}"
  end
end

module A
  module B
    include Comparable
    @a = 1
    def self.b; end
    def c; end
    module C
    end
  end
end

Observer.show_all(A::B)
  # owner of methods = [:b]
  # owner of instance methods = [:c]
  # instance variables = [:@a]
  # ancestors = [A::B, Comparable]
  # included modules = [Comparable]

class D; end
class E<D; end
class F<E
  include Comparable
  @a = 1
  def self.e; end
  def f; end
end

Observer.show_all(F)
  # owner of methods = [:e]
  # owner of instance methods = [:f]
  # instance variables = [:@a]
  # ancestors = [F, Comparable, E, D, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
  # included modules = [Comparable, Kernel]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do not understand the question wrong.

You can do like this, to read the property of `Module`.

Example:

1st Version:

```
require "nokogiri"
p Nokogiri.methods # It will print for you all methods in that Module,
                   # also available methods from ruby.
```

2nd Version

```
x = require "nokogiri"
p x.methods #available methods there private, public, protected methods and etc...
p x.private_methods # prints bunch of private methods, [:Nokogiri]
```

Comment: require returns boolean, not the module.